# unable to run testng xml when I use groups

Tags: java, selenium, testng

I created a testng.xml file to run few tests which are tagged as smoke tests(using groups). Now I try to run this xml file as a testng suite but it fails all the test cases. The browser doesnt even open. Refer the below xml file.

```
<suite name="Smoke Test" verbose="1">
    <parameter name="browser" value="chrome"></parameter>
    <test name="Smoke Test">
        <groups>
            <run>
                <include name="smoketest" />
            </run>
        </groups>

        <packages>
            <package name="com.banner.tests" />
        </packages>

    </test>
</suite>
```

Error Message is:

```
java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
    at com.cub.tests.Coupons.addCouponAsSignedInUser(Coupons.java:125)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at org.testng.internal.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeMethod(MethodInvocationHelper.java:108)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeMethod(Invoker.java:661)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeTestMethod(Invoker.java:869)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeTestMethods(Invoker.java:1193)
    at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.invokeTestMethods(TestMethodWorker.java:126)
    at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.run(TestMethodWorker.java:109)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.privateRun(TestRunner.java:744)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.run(TestRunner.java:602)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runTest(SuiteRunner.java:380)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runSequentially(SuiteRunner.java:375)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.privateRun(SuiteRunner.java:340)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.run(SuiteRunner.java:289)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.runSuite(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:52)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.run(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:86)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesSequentially(TestNG.java:1301)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesLocally(TestNG.java:1226)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuites(TestNG.java:1144)
    at org.testng.TestNG.run(TestNG.java:1115)
    at org.testng.remote.AbstractRemoteTestNG.run(AbstractRemoteTestNG.java:132)
    at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.initAndRun(RemoteTestNG.java:230)
    at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.main(RemoteTestNG.java:76)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at java.io.File.<init>(File.java:277)
    at com.relevantcodes.extentreports.Report.setFilePath(Report.java:527)
    at com.relevantcodes.extentreports.ExtentReports.<init>(ExtentReports.java:80)
    at com.relevantcodes.extentreports.ExtentReports.<init>(ExtentReports.java:375)
    at com.common.utils.ExtentManager.getReporter(ExtentManager.java:13)
    at com.common.utils.ExtentTestManager.<clinit>(ExtentTestManager.java:11)
    ... 26 more
```

Below is the SuiteBase Code that I have which will set up my driver:

```
@BeforeSuite
    public void beforeSuiteActivties() {
        logger.info("Performing BeforeSuite activities..");
        setApplicationProperties();
        testURL = getTestURL();
        setTestData();
        hubURL = getHubAddress();
        if(banner.equalsIgnoreCase("MACKENTHUNS")){
        updateXML = new UpdateXML();
        updateXML.updateTestData(testDataFileName);
        }
        extentReportPath = System.getProperty("user.dir") + "\\test-output\\extent\\" + banner + "\\extentreport.html";
        extent = ExtentManager.getReporter();
    }

    @AfterSuite
    public void afterSuiteActivities() {
        extent.close();
    }

    @Parameters({ "browser" })
    @BeforeTest
    public void beforeTestActivities(String browserName) {
        logger.info("Performing Before Test Activities");
        setUpDriver(browserName);
        setObjects();
    }

    @BeforeMethod
    public void beforeMethodActivities(Method method) {
        logger.info("Performing Before Method Activities");
        ExtentTestManager.startTest(method.getName());
        /*if (!linkExists(testURL)) {
            throw new SkipException("The test link --> " + testURL + " is not working");
        }*/
        commonPage = new CommonPage(getDriver());
        boolean isSignInVisible = false;
        isSignInVisible = commonPage.isSignInPresent();
        logger.info("Is User Logged Out? " + isSignInVisible);
        if (!isSignInVisible) {
            try {
                commonPage.clickFooterLink(CommonPage.FOOTERLINK_LOGOUT);
                CommonPage.waitForPageToBeReady(getDriver());
            } catch (Exception exception) {
                logger.error("Error occurred while trying to click on Logout link");
            }
        } else
            logger.info("Sign In link is available for login so proceeding with next test method execution");

    }

    public void setUpDriver(String browserName) {
        try {
            if (testURL != "" && hubURL != "") {
                logger.info("Test Environment -- > " + environment);
                logger.info("Validation on URL -- > " + testURL);
                logger.info("Hub URL -- > " + hubURL);
                driver = new RemoteWebDriver(new URL(hubURL), getBrowserCapabilities(browserName));
                setWebDriver(driver);
                getDriver().get(testURL);
                getDriver().manage().window().maximize();
                getDriver().manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(25, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
            } else {
                logger.error("Either test URL or Hub URL is empty... So cannot procced with the test execution");
            }
        } catch (Exception exception) {
            logger.error("Something went wrong while initializing the driver");
            exception.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    @AfterMethod
    public void afterMethodActivities(ITestResult result) {
        logger.info("Performing After Method Activities");
        commonPage = new CommonPage(getDriver());
        try {
            commonPage.closePopup();
        } catch (Exception exception) {
            logger.error("Something went wrong while closing the popup --> After Method");
            //exception.printStackTrace();
        }

        if (result.getStatus() == ITestResult.FAILURE) {
            ExtentTestManager.getTest().log(LogStatus.FAIL, result.getThrowable());
        } else if (result.getStatus() == ITestResult.SKIP) {
            ExtentTestManager.getTest().log(LogStatus.SKIP, "Test skipped " + result.getThrowable());
        } else {
            ExtentTestManager.getTest().log(LogStatus.PASS, "Test passed");
        }

        if(commonPage.isAlertPresent()){
            commonPage.closeAlert();
        }

        ExtentManager.getReporter().endTest(ExtentTestManager.getTest());
        ExtentManager.getReporter().flush();
    }

    public void setObjects() {
        logger.info("Setting the object repository file");
        objectFileName = resourceFolder + "\\" + banner + "\\webobjects.properties";
        logger.info("Banner - " + banner + "/" + "Repository file - " + objectFileName);
        try {
            webObjectProperties = new Properties();
            fip = new FileInputStream(new File(objectFileName));
            webObjectProperties.load(fip);
        } catch (Exception exception) {
            logger.error("Error occurred while reading the webobjects properties file");
            exception.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public void setTestData() {
        banner = getBanner();
        logger.info("Setting the test data file");
        if (environment.contains("prod")) {
            testDataFileName = resourceFolder + "\\" + banner + "\\prodtestdata.xml";
        } else {
            testDataFileName = resourceFolder + "\\" + banner + "\\testdata.xml";
        }
        logger.info("Banner - " + banner + "/" + "TestData file - " + testDataFileName);
    }

    public static String getBanner() {
        if (System.getProperty("banner") == null) {
            try {
                return properties.getProperty("banner");
            } catch (Exception exception) {
                logger.error("Error occurred while reading the banner value");
                exception.printStackTrace();
            }
        } else {
            return System.getProperty("banner");
        }
        return "";
    }

    private static DesiredCapabilities getBrowserCapabilities(String browserType) {
        DesiredCapabilities capability;
        switch (browserType) {
        case "firefox":
            System.out.println("Opening firefox driver");
            capability = DesiredCapabilities.firefox();
            // capability.setCapability("marionette", true);
            capability.setBrowserName("firefox");
            capability.setVersion("ANY");
            capability.setPlatform(Platform.ANY);
            return capability;
        case "chrome":
            System.out.println("Opening chrome driver");
            return DesiredCapabilities.chrome();
        case "internet explorer":
            System.out.println("Opening IE driver");
            capability = DesiredCapabilities.internetExplorer();
            System.out.println("IE PlatForm : " + capability.getPlatform());
            System.out.println("IE Browser Name :" + capability.getBrowserName());
            capability.setPlatform(Platform.WINDOWS);
            capability.setBrowserName("internet explorer");
            capability.setCapability(InternetExplorerDriver.INTRODUCE_FLAKINESS_BY_IGNORING_SECURITY_DOMAINS, true);
            capability.setCapability(InternetExplorerDriver.IE_ENSURE_CLEAN_SESSION, true);
            capability.setCapability(InternetExplorerDriver.IGNORE_ZOOM_SETTING, true);
            return capability;
        case "safari":
            System.out.println("Opening Safari driver");
            capability = DesiredCapabilities.safari();
            SafariOptions safariOptions = new SafariOptions();
            safariOptions.setUseCleanSession(true);
            safariOptions.setUseTechnologyPreview(true);
            capability.setCapability(SafariOptions.CAPABILITY, safariOptions);
            capability.setPlatform(Platform.MAC);
            return capability;
        default:
            System.out.println("browser : " + browserType + " is invalid, Launching Firefox as browser of choice..");
            return DesiredCapabilities.firefox();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Can some one help what could be the issue?

Comment: Please update the question with your code block or Class file please.

Comment: Added the suitebase code. Please let me know if this is not sufficient

Comment: `ExtentManager.getReporter();` <-- this is the line that fails. Maybe it should be `ExtentManager.getReporter(extentReportPath)`?

Comment: seems like nothing to do with the testng. failing in extent report.  could you check if this is failing without group as well?

Comment: it works when I execute testng.xml without group tags, but I needed groups for my smoke tests execution.

Comment: Which version of extent report are you using?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add `alwaysRun = true` to your `@BeforeSuite`/`@AfterSuite` and try again. You should be good.

The problem is that your before and after suite config methods are not part of any groups and that is where you seem to be initialising your extent reports.

When you run by groups, TestNG will execute only those tests/configs that are part of the group.

To ensure that irrespective of what group was chosen to run, if TestNG should always run your config methods, you should add `alwaysRun=true` to them.